# Getting GPS position with R package leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm using the R package leaftlet to create a map with some markers, but I also need to show the GPS position on the map for movile devices.

I know that this is possible in leaflet with the [location method](http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile.html) and some javascript but it seems that this method is not available in the R package: "leaflet".

What is the best way to show the GPS position in a map generated with R and leaflet?

Comment: Not familiar with leaflet, but this post seems too broad, could you add [reproducible data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and expected output, dummy plot?

Comment: This may help - https://github.com/byzheng/leafletplugins - but it's likely that you'd need to fork the leaflet repo and add this as an optional parameter to the `setView()` function and do a PR.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr, that looks promising. I'll have a look and comment my experience after.

Answer (score 13):

*Important: Open the map in a browser not inside RStudio! And allow the request for location access!*

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()

map <- addControlGPS(map, options = gpsOptions(position = "topleft", activate = TRUE, 
                                               autoCenter = TRUE, maxZoom = 10, 
                                               setView = TRUE))
activateGPS(map)
```

Very cool feature, thanks for the question!

Comment: Nice solution, is there any way to store the data from the GPS into a dataframeas well as displaying it?

Comment: Thats a good question. I didnt find a quick solution, Probably it would be a good idea to post a new question for that. You can reference it here, then i can also take a  look.

Comment: @BigDataScientist; thank you for a good comment and interesting solution.